# Querying another easy table for push notification message

Tags: push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I have two easy tables configured in my Azure App backend:

- `Services` with `Id` and `ServiceName` properties
- `ServiceDetails` with `Id`, `ServiceID` and `ServiceDetailDate` properties

Whenever a new `ServiceDetails` entry is inserted, I want to send a message to my users via Push Notifications containing information about `ServiceDetailDate` and `ServiceName`.

So my question is how can I query another table to obtain information from it? In this case the `ServiceID` (from `ServiceDetails` table) is known, so I want to get the `ServiceName` from `Services`. Which code should I add to extract the `ServiceName` from the `serviceInfo` object (in the payload message) to my script to fulfill this request?

Actually I'm not sure about the query and serviceInfo instructions, so if I'm wrong with the code, don't hesitate to point me in the right direction.

```
var azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps'),
promises = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/utilities/promises'),
logger = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/logger'),
queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query');

var table = azureMobileApps.table();

table.insert(function (context) {
  var query =  queries.create('Services');
  var serviceInfo = query.where({'Id': context.item.ServiceID});

  var payload = '{"messageParam": "Your service -service name- has been added on ' + context.item.ServiceDetailDate + '" }';  

  return context.execute()
      .then(function (results) {
          if (context.push) {
              context.push.send(null, payload, function (error) {
                  if (error) {
                      logger.error('Error while sending push notification: ', error);
                  } else {
                      logger.info('Push notification sent successfully!');
                  }
              });
          }
          return results;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          logger.error('Error while running context.execute: ', error);
  });
});

module.exports = table;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to query another easy table in `ServiceDetails.js`.

```
table.insert(function (context) {
    return context.tables('Services')
        .where({ Id: context.item.ServiceID })
        .select('ServiceName')
        .read()
        .then(function (data) {
            var message = 'Your service ' + data[0].ServiceName + ' has been added on ' + context.item.ServiceDetailDate;
            var payload = '{"messageParam": "' + message + '"}'; 

            return context.execute().then(function (results) {
                //..
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It works and I finished my app on time :)